# Same output every time module is run

Tags: python

```
num=input("Enter number: ")
if num >="0" and num <="9":
    print("Number consists of a single digit")
elif num >="10" and num <="99":
    print("Number consists of double digits")
elif num >="100" and num <="999":
    print("Number consists of triple digits")
else:
    print("Number consists of more than 3 digits")
```

I keep getting "Number consists of a single digit" every time I run it. I tried changing the data type from str to int but then I get "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'" - which I don't understand what it means by that? So I went back to my original answer but don't see any errors. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is because you're using strings instead of integers. You want to replace all your instances of numbers ("10", "3", "1") with (10, 3, 1) - no quotation marks. As well as that, you want to **cast** your `num` variable into an integer (because it returns a string). So change to `int(input(...))`.

Comment: You need to call `int()` on the results of `input()`, and you *also* need to make your comparisons ints. For example, the first comparison should be `if num >= 0 and num <= 9:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python compares string lexicographically

Try this :

```
num=int(input("Enter number: "))
if num >=0 and num <=9:
    print("Number consists of a single digit")
elif num >=10 and num <=99:
    print("Number consists of double digits")
elif num >=100 and num <=999:
    print("Number consists of triple digits")
else:
    print("Number consists of more than 3 digits")
```